# RegExp in java(android) to prevent other urls except one

Tags: java, android, regex, webview

I am creating an app where i am using webview. I want only my website domain pages should load into my app(webview).

If some other domain is clicked from my app, it should ask to open in other application (browser).
At the first hit, i did the following to prevent other domains-

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
                /* url=http://mywebsite.com */
                if(!urlNewString.contains(url)){

                    view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlNewString)));
                    return true;
                }
```

But the problem is it will also open http://blogs.mywebsite.com and all other subdomains like this in browser and not in my application's webview.
Can anyone suggest me a regex to do the needful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `java.net.URL` class to split out the relevant information, such as:

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://blogs.mywebsite.com/foo/bar/baz.html");

boolean on_my_http_site = url.getProtocol().equals("http") && 
                         (url.getHost().equals("mywebsite.com") ||
                          url.getHost().endsWith(".mywebsite.com"));
```